# SQL Server Foreign Key for Different Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I have an SQL Server 2012 Express database with the following situation.
I have a `Sales`, a `Purchase`, and a `Movement` table.
Both `Sales` and `Purchase` are summarized in the `Movement` table.

But I would like to control where the data comes from.
Basically:

```
MOVEMENT_ID     TABLE_ID     RECORD_ID     PROD     QTY
1               PURCHASE     1             PENCIL   10
2               PURCHASE     2             ERASER   5
3               SALES        1             PENCIL   1
4               PURCHASE     3             MARKER   10
```

Don't worry about the normalization part, I just want to figure out if I can have a foreign key on the `Record_ID` column that links to the record of the table specified in the `Table_ID` column.
So...

- on `MovementID=1`, I want the first record of `Purchase` table
- on `MovementID=3`, I want the first record of `Sales` table

Is this at all possible? If yes, how?

Comment: *"Don't worry about the normalization part"* is like saying don't worry about that flat tire on your car, it'll drive fine.

Comment: I think you'd be better off with three columns `Purchase_Id, Sales_Id, Source_Table`

Comment: my question is more theoretical. i don't want some db evangelical such as yourself to get all righteous about something i'm going to be doing anyways.

Comment: If you normalize, this problem will go away - one way or another. Search for "supertype/subtype", there are 3 ways to resolve this kind of problem.

Comment: @CogentP Foundation is important for a good concept.

Comment: T I, so your saying to create a special column for each table that inserts onto the movement table? so if 5 tables write into movement table, i should have 5 columsn?

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind this? Are you trying to Create a foreign Key relationship to an un-related column in such a way that the values don't match?

Comment: If you insist on using such an approach, you cannot establish *real* referential integrity. You cannot use ID+Type to somehow reference the `Sales` table once, and the `Purchase` table another time. Just cannot be done. Don'it do it - this is a horrible design idea..... use separate ID columns in `Movements` for sales and purchase - one of them is not null for every row (and the other will be null)

Comment: @Zane, the purchase and sales table have data that I need to retrieve, such as Date, Customer, Supplier, etc. If I could dynamically link the fk to the right table based on the table that wrote the insertion, I would be able to retrieve the data without much fuss. If not, it would require more coding and resources to get it done. i'm just wondering if there is something to this, or am i hitting a dead end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like Movement is really a generalization of Purchase or Sale.  If so, consider using [shared-primary-key](/questions/tagged/shared-primary-key).

This will obviate the problem of mixing different types of FKs in one column.  The PK in the Movement table will reference the PK in either the Purchase or the Sale table, as the case may be.  Fewer columns and also less confusion.

Comment: thanks walter, thats what i was looking for! I can do the research from here!!

Answer (score 1):

> Is this at all possible?

Not directly, and I would warmly recommend separate fields with separate FKs (as others have already suggested).

*However*, since you are using MS SQL Server, you could do it indirectly like this:

1. Create a persisted<sup>1</sup> **computed column** SALE_ID that is:

   - equal to RECORD_ID when TABLE_ID = 'SALES'
   - and NULL otherwise.
2. Create a persisted computed column PURCHASE_ID that is:

   - equal to RECORD_ID when TABLE_ID = 'PURCHASE'
   - and NULL otherwise.
3. Create a FK from SALE_ID to Sales table and a separate FK from PURCHASE_ID to Purchase table.

For example:

```
ALTER TABLE Movement
    ADD SALE_ID AS IIF(TABLE_ID = 'SALES', RECORD_ID, NULL) PERSISTED
    REFERENCES Sales (SALE_ID);

ALTER TABLE Movement
    ADD PURCHASE_ID AS IIF(TABLE_ID = 'PURCHASE', RECORD_ID, NULL) PERSISTED
    REFERENCES Purchase (PURCHASE_ID);
```

[[SQL Fiddle]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7dab2/4)

---

*<sup>1</sup> SQL Server forbids creating FOREIGN KEY on non-persisted computed columns.*

Comment: thanks Branko, i gave you a +One for helping out. I'm going to try walter's as its close to my original idea. if it becomes obviously hard to maintain then i'll go with a separate column for each fk.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you are doing this for, then a denormalized table like this might not be too bad (i.e. if it's just for querying/analyzing). However it could become hard to maintain (eg. what happens when the IDs from these tables have different data types etc). some examples of queries you might do though

```
;WITH SalesMovement AS
(
    SELECT * FROM Movement
    WHERE TableName = 'Sales'
)
SELECT PROD, SUM(QTY) FROM SalesMovement
GROUP BY PROD
```

```
;WITH PurchaseMovement AS
(
    SELECT * FROM Movement
    WHERE TableName = 'Purchase'
)
SELECT * FROM Purchase p
INNER JOIN PurchaseMovement pm ON pm.Record_Id = p.Id
```

```
;WITH PurchaseMovement AS
(
    SELECT * FROM Movement
    WHERE TableName = 'Purchase'
)
, SalesMovement AS
(
    SELECT * FROM Movement
    WHERE TableName = 'Sales'
)
SELECT * FROM Purchase p, 
INNER JOIN Sales s ON s.SaleDate = p.PurchaseDate
INNER JOIN PurchaseMovement pm ON pm.Record_Id = p.Id
INNER JOIN SalesMovement sm ON sm.Record_Id = s.Id
```

Whenever you wanted to join back to original data you would have to filter, cast and what have you which may become a real pita further down the line

Another thing to consider is whether something like the `SUM(Qty) = SUM(ProductsSold) + SUM(ProductsSales)` makes any sense, you'd have to be careful of this sort of 'misuse' of the data in the table.